# prevent enduser to use CTRL-X / CUT on cell content

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to prevent the end-user to cut cell contents? Thus prevent using CTRL-X (and spreadsheet Menu EDIT-> Cut) but allow edit and copy cell content.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague... I suppose you are trying to limit access to certain cells to 'read only' ... how is that related to GAS ?

in the spreadsheet menu you can define a named region (that can be a single cell) and choose who has access to it. As simple as that .
[image]

Comment: the problem is, when i set a validation rule to a cell and the user cuts the cell en pastes it elsewhere the validation on the original cell is gone, it is moved to, which i don't want to.